# Simulating collapsible toolbar

Tags: android

I have searched for a possible solution to imitating the collapsible toolbar but I can't seem to start it with my current knowledge on handling complex layouts.

[image: initial view]

From the layout above, I have a docked layout above, an imageview, 2 textviews. What I want to do is when I scroll up, the imageview will transfer its self at the top right, the textview without border will be pushed at the top, and the last textview should disappear.

Just like this.

[image]

As of now, I was able to move the ImageView to the required position when scrolling with this code:

```
  private void scaleImage(float x, float y) {
    movingView.setScaleX(x);
    movingView.setScaleY(y);
    movingView.setPivotX(1.3f * movingView.getWidth());
    movingView.setPivotY(1.5f * movingView.getHeight());
  }


  @Override
  protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
      float offsetFactorDown = (float) (getScrollY()) / (float) scrollRange;
      float scaleFactor = 1F - offsetFactorDown * 0.9F;

      scaleImage(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
  }
```

The `getScrollY()` is not consistent which only gives me the right position when I am scrolling slowly. What else can I use to be the basis for the offset which is consistent?

Comment: checl this http://saulmm.github.io/mastering-coordinator if it helps

Comment: My way to go will be to implement scroll listener. Determine the scenario when you want to make that transition onScroll . When you meet this scenario, you can animate the image to the result position ( use `ObjectAnimator` so that final result is where your image view stays) . You let your borderless text as it is as it is already scrolled up and you set the visibility of bordered text to `Gone` or `Invisible` based on what you expecting.

Comment: @Jimmy I updated my question. I hope you can help me with this.